# How to get ListView ID from two Relative Layout in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Im using DrawerLayout,in that i have two relative layout with **ListView** for left drawer and right drawer.So please help me to get ListView ID from these two relative layout and this is my XML

```
<!-- Left Drawrer -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/LeftDrawer"
android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/categoryview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

 <!-- Right Drawer -->
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RightDrawer"
android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/settingview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried with **OnItemClickListener()** but it worked only for categoryview ListView.please help.

Comment: Add code where you putting click listener for "settingview" listview

Comment: //Drawer Layout ListView
ArrayList<ListItemDetails> result = GetSearchResults();
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.categoryview);
lv.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(result,getApplicationContext()));
ArrayList<ListItemDetails> result2 = GetSearchResults2();
ListView lv2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.settingview);
lv2.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter2(result2,getApplicationContext()));
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
lv2.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

Each ListView has an `android:id`. Just use `findViewById()` in your Activity like with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Use inside on create() method

```
lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                        //Code here as per your requirement
                    }
                }
            });
```